# What is the difference between GROUP BY and DISTINCT?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the table with the following data

```
empid   empname deptid   address
--------------------------------
aa76    John     6       34567
aa75    rob      4       23456
aa71    smith    3       12345
aa74    dave     2       12345
a77     blake    2       12345
aa73    andrew   3       12345
aa90    sam      1       12345
aa72    will     6       34567
aa70    rahul    5       34567
```

I've used the following queries:

```
select deptid, EMPID ,EMPNAME ,ADDRESS
from mytable
group by 1,2,3,4
```

Which gives the result:

```
deptid  empid  empname address
------------------------------
1       aa90   sam      12345
2       aa74   dave     12345
2       aa77   blake    12345
3       aa71   smith    12345
3       aa73   andrew   12345
4       aa75   rob      23456
5       aa70   rahul    34567
6       aa76   John     34567
6       aa72   will     34567
```

And for the query:

```
select distinct (deptid),EMPID,EMPNAME,ADDRESS
from mytable
```

The result set is:

```
deptid empid empname address   
----------------------------
1      aa90  sam     12345
2      aa74  dave    12345
2      aa77  blake   12345
3      aa71  smith   12345
3      aa73  andrew  12345
4      aa75  rob     23456
5      aa70  rahul   34567
6      aa72  will    34567
6      aa76  John    34567
```

In the second query though I've given `DISTINCT` for DEPTID, how come I got the duplicate DEPTID...

Could you explain this?

Comment: I guess you need to first explain what result you are expecting ? DISTINCT works on all columns. so your second query gave you 2 unique rows of data even though deptid is same. Use GROUP BY  for aggregate functions like count or sum.

Comment: Referring to a column by position in the SELECT clause is called an ordinal. IE: `group by 1,2,3,4` - it's not recommended in case the SELECT columns change.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426723/sql-group-by-versus-distinct

Comment: As a side-note; on Teradata 13.10 (and older versions), using DISTINCT can cause a sort operation, which is slower than GROUP BY. So from a performance perspective, one should prefer GROUP BY over DISTINCT wherever possible.
I think this is fixed in the 14.10 version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DISTINCT` refer to distinct records as a whole, not distinct fields in the record.

Comment: This is were i was confused.. I was expecting distinct to return distinct column... Its cleared for me now..

Answer (score 10):

[`DISTINCT`](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-distinct-sql-tutorial/) eliminates repeating rows.  [`GROUP BY`](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-group-by-sql-tutorial/) groups unique records, and allows you to perform aggregate functions.

Answer (score 2):

`DISTINCT` works only on the entire row. Don't be mislead into thinking `SELECT DISTINCT(A), B` does something different. This is equivalent to `SELECT DISTINCT A, B`

Answer (score 1):

While group by all columns and distinct will give you the same results in Teradata, they have different algorithms behind the scenes and you will generally get better performance from using group by than from using distinct. I believe there were plans to have both implemented the same way, but they are still different in the version I'm using (v2r6) and I haven't tried on Teradata 12 yet.

Comment: See the explanation between how GROUP BY vs DISTINCT is handled by the optimizer here: http://forums.teradata.com/forum/enterprise/distinct-vs-group-by-insert-vs-create-as

It appears that in Teradata 13 that is the point where the optimizer improves the performance of DISTINCT as indicated in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Group By and Distinct both will work Same. Comparing to Distinct Group By Gives good performance because it processes less rows and occupies less spool memory

Answer (score -1):

Distinct will not work fine with multi column. though given distinct on single column but it gives the unique combination of specified columns.

So, Group by gives the unique records and can do aggregates too.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to explain the difference but I give you the examples _with_queries_ through this you can better understand the difference between `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT`.

**Question: How many people are in each unique state in the customers table**

```
select distinct(state), count(*) from customers;

RESULT

Washington  17
----------------------------------------------------------

select State, count(*) from customers GROUP BY STATE;

RESULT

**Arizona    6
Colorado         2
Hawaii           1
Idaho            1
North Carolina   1
Oregon           2
Sourth Carolina  1
Washington   2
Wisconsin    1**
```

**Just make your own table and  check the result**

Comment: This is definitely not the result in Teradata (and shouldn't be in other DBMSes), it will result in a syntax error. Which DBMS did you use for it? MySQL?