# Query for Searching in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

```
members (id, name, email)
members_kids (id, member_id, kids_name, kids_age)
member_kids_activity_preferences (id, kid_id, activity_id)
```

I have an array of activities `(4, 10, 12, 14)`

What I need to do is select distinct email addresses from members WHOSE kids have a preference for `4,10,12,14` from the `member_kids_activity_preferences` table. How do i do it using 1 query ?

Jason

Answer (score 2):

Quick shot:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email FROM members m
    JOIN members_kids k ON m.id = k.member_id
    JOIN member_kids_activity_preferences p ON k.id = p.kid_id
  WHERE p.activity_id IN (4,10,12,14)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT m.name,m.email
FROM members m
   JOIN members_kids k
      ON m.id = k.member_id
   JOIN member_kids_activity_preferences ap
      ON k.id = ap.kid_id
WHERE ap.id IN (4, 10, 12, 14)
GROUP BY m.name,m.email
```

Comment: i've edited my answer to use GROUP BY istead of DINSTINC just to propose something different from Mchl and glglgl as we posted almost simultaneous

Comment: here is an interesting question about DISTINCT vs GROUP BY: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426723/sql-group-by-versus-distinct

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  m.email
FROM
  members AS m
INNER JOIN
  members_kids AS mk
ON
  m.id = mk.member_id
INNER JOIN
  member_kids_activity_preferences AS mkap
ON
  mk.id = mkap.kid_id
WHERE
  mkap.activity_id IN (4,10,12,14)
```