# How to get only 1 row of each similar content?

Tags: php, sql

I Have a private message system on my site and i'm trying to pull all subject's on the messages.
I need to show any subject once.

so if I have this subjects:

```
hey
hello
hey
good morning
good morning
```

I need to print this:

```
hey
hello
good morning
```

I can just cross it out with if, but I guess there is a better way with sql.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 : [**DISTINCT**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)

```
SELECT DISTINCT subject 
FROM my_table
```

Option 2 : [**GROUP BY**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
 SELECT subjects
 FROM my_table
 GROUP BY subjects
```

#### Difference between [*GROUP BY*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) and  [*DISTINCT*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)

Distinct is used to filter unique records out of the records that satisfy the query criteria.

Group by clause is used to group the data upon which the aggregate functions are fired and the output is returned based on the columns in the group by clause. It has its own limitations such as all the columns that are in the select query apart from the aggregate functions have to be the part of the Group by clause.

- See [***this***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477552/mysql-what-is-the-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct) and [***this***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164319/is-there-any-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct) for the reference .

Comment: Great! The explanation is what made this answer a good answer (and different from all the others here).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT subject FROM emails;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL.

```
select distinct subjects
  from YOUR_TABLE.
```

or

```
Select subjects
  from YOU_TABLE
group by subjects
```

Comment: Please add a little information about when to use `GROUP BY` and when to use `DISTINCT`. Your answer implies that these two are the same which is not quite true.

Comment: Distinct and group by are similar but not equals. 
For instance.
In a table with 1000 records with 100 repetitions and using a function, the most difference is performace.

select distinc FUNCTION(COLUMN) from table
return 100 records and evaluate the function 1000 times once per record.

select FUNCTION(COLUMN) from TABLE group by FUNCTION(COLUMN)
are equal.

Comment: But
select FUNCTION(COLUMN) from TABLE group by COLUMN
Return 100 records and evaluate only 100 times the function.