# Postgres is a performing a sequential scan instead of index scan

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with about 10 million rows in it and an index on a date field. When I try and extract the unique values of the indexed field Postgres runs a sequential scan even though the result set has only 26 items. Why is the optimiser picking this plan? And what can I do avoid it?

```
explain select "labelDate" from pages group by "labelDate";
                              QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=524616.78..524617.04 rows=26 width=4)
   Group Key: "labelDate"
   ->  Seq Scan on pages  (cost=0.00..499082.42 rows=10213742 width=4)
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Are your statistics up to date?

Comment: Yes, I've run analyze full and reindex

Comment: I guess you would have better chance on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, there's a dedicated forum for DB questions? I'll give it a go.

Comment: This question has been answered on DBA. It turns out that there is a known issue in Postgres with indices with relatively few unique values in a large table. Seems counterintuitive but I actually know that this should be a foreign key dependency.
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem here is that the query planner wants to read the whole table because you have a `GROUP BY` clause even though you do not use any aggregate function. It therefore looks similar to the issue of ["Why is count(*) so slow"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11250253/3304426) which you will find in many forms in [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) questions.

In your case, the query is a bit odd. Your question is answered with this simple query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "labelDate" FROM pages;
```

Comment: That doesn't run any faster. As COUNT isn't used a scan shouldn't be required.