# Postgresql DISTINCT and other fields gives Missing FROM-clause

Tags: postgresql, distinct, where-clause

I want to search DISTINCT on a Postgresql 9.4 table with about 300 000 records. It takes almost 8 seconds. I read on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250253/postgresql-countdistinct-very-slow) that using this could speed it up. And it really did. Down to 0.26 sec.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table_name) AS temp;
```

Is much faster than

```
COUNT(DISTINCT(column_name))
```

When I write this I get the result but I want to add a WHERE clause.

This works but takes over 7 sec.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(species)) FROM darwincore2
WHERE darwincore2.dataeier ILIKE '%nnog%'
```

This works (0.26 sec.) but fails when I add the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT species FROM darwincore2) as temp
WHERE darwincore2.dataeier ILIKE '%nnog%'
```

with:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table &quot;darwincore2&quot;
```

Anyone know how I can fix this? Or am I trying to do something that does not work??

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. `distinct(column_name)` makes no sense

Answer (score 2):

The `WHERE` clause should be in the subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT species 
    FROM darwincore2
    WHERE darwincore2.dataeier ILIKE '%nnog%'
    ) as temp
```

Comment: Thanks @klin. This worked just great and I guess I can add any filtering inside the FROM(....) section?

Comment: A subquery is a normal query, so you can filter data as you want. Treat a subquery as a virtual table, from which you can select data with an outer query. Btw, such a subquery is formally known as *derived table*.