# How to count distinct on a group by hstore key with join?

Tags: postgresql, join, count, distinct, hstore

I'm trying to do the following with postgres:

- count distinct
- table joins
- group by hstore key

I don't think I'm too far, but **the count distinct isn't added up per group by values**.

[Here is the code on rextester.com](http://rextester.com/GXO21807)

What I have so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pets.id),locations.attr -> 'country' as country
FROM pets,photos,locations
WHERE photos.pet_id = pets.id
AND photos.location_id = locations.id
GROUP BY pets.id,locations.attr -> 'country';
```

Which gives me:

[image]

Whereas I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the `pets.id` from `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pets.id),locations.attr -> 'country' as country
FROM pets,photos,locations
WHERE photos.pet_id = pets.id
AND photos.location_id = locations.id
GROUP BY locations.attr -> 'country';
```

#### EDIT:

You don't really need to join the pets table. Also, use explicit JOIN syntax:

```
select
    l.attr -> 'country' country,
    count(distinct p.pet_id)
from photos p
inner join locations l
on p.location_id = l.id
group by l.attr -> 'country';
```

Without using `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
select 
    country, count (pet_id)
from (
    select
        l.attr -> 'country' country,
        p.pet_id
    from photos p
    inner join locations l
    on p.location_id = l.id
    group by l.attr -> 'country', p.pet_id
) t
group by country;
```

http://rextester.com/YVR16306

Comment: Indeed (tired). Since this was an easy one, would you happen to know how to adapt the query to use the more efficient `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT` instead of `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250253/postgresql-countdistinct-very-slow#answer-14732410

Comment: Beautiful! if I may ask, what's the added value of using the explicit `JOIN` syntax versus what I was doing?

Comment: The explicit join is modern and more clear and easy to understand whereas the other syntax is 20 years old.