# postgresql group count distinct using fast way

Tags: postgresql, group-by, distinct

I got table `T` with 2 column as follow example:

```
C1      C2
----------
A       x
A       x
A       y
B       x
B       x
```

I want to count number of distinct `C1` for each value in `C2`. This result should be like:

```
C1      distinct count
----------------------
A       2               // count distinct x,x,y = 2
B       1               // count distinct x,x = 1
```

it is easy to come out with a SQL query like this

```
select C1, count(distinct C2) from T group by C1
```

however, as discussed in [postgresql COUNT(DISTINCT …) very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250253/postgresql-countdistinct-very-slow), this query yield poor performance.  I would like to use the improved query (`count (*) (select distinct ...)`) as suggested in that article but I don't know how to form the query with group by.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this query if you want avoid `DISTINCT` keyword

Sample Data:

```
stackoverflow=# select * from T;
 c1 | c2 
----+----
 A  | x
 A  | x
 A  | y
 B  | x
 B  | x
(5 rows)
```

Query:

```
stackoverflow=# WITH count_distinct as (SELECT C1 FROM T GROUP BY c1,c2)
SELECT c1,count(c1) FROM count_distinct GROUP BY C1;  --updated missing group by
```

Output:

```
 c1 | count 
----+-------
 B  |     1
 A  |     2
(2 rows)
```

Same output, but you should try the performance first.

Comment: You missed `GROUP BY c1` for second query