# Speed up an activerecord query for distinct count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, postgresql-10

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14732410/695186) for speeding up a query, saying to use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table_name) AS temp;
```

instead of

```
COUNT(DISTINCT column_name)
```

How would one go about writing this change in activerecord (short of just writing as an sql statement)?

Comment: Well, this answer is 5 years old, optimizer get more sophisticated. You should try first, if it actually returns a different plan (you might also check `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT column_name FROM table_name GROUP BY column_name) AS temp;`, which is another rewrite). But a decent optimizer should create the same plan anyway.

Comment: I'd like to compare the plan for both but haven't had time. The timed results are similar though, so you may be correct - it might not matter.