# How can I join multiple tables for count?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables named `houses`, `trees`, `rivers`. All of these tables have `city_id` column. I want to group total counts by cities. Cities are in another table.
My database is postgresql.

```
city_name    trees    houses      rivers
City-1       1000     200         1
City-2       300      100         2
City-3       4000     210         4
```

I can get for trees

```
SELECT 
    city.name as city_name, 
    count(*) as trees
FROM trees as t, cities as city
WHERE t.city_id = city.city_id
GROUP BY city.name
```

But I could not join three tables in sama query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid issues with duplication of rows in a `JOIN` it's probably easiest to do the aggregation in subqueries and then `JOIN` them:

```
SELECT c.name, 
       COALESCE(t.cnt, 0) AS trees,
       COALESCE(h.cnt, 0) AS houses,
       COALESCE(r.cnt, 0) AS rivers
FROM cities c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT city_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
           FROM trees
           GROUP BY city_id) t ON t.city_id = c.city_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT city_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
           FROM houses
           GROUP BY city_id) h ON h.city_id = c.city_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT city_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
           FROM rivers
           GROUP BY city_id) r ON r.city_id = c.city_id
```

We use a `LEFT JOIN` in case a given city has no trees, houses or rivers.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=701a9f7cd8bcc1947513abcd0cb0b337)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Nick's answer:

```
SELECT 
    city.name as city_name, 
    count(distinct t.id) as trees,
    count(distinct h.id) as houses,
    count(distinct r.id) as rivers
FROM  cities as city
left join trees as t on t.city_id = city.city_id
left join rivers as r on r.city_id = city.city_id
left join houses as h on h.city_id = city.city_id
GROUP BY city.name
```

--

Not sure of the performance implications specifically with Postgres, but here's a (fairly old, so things might have moved on since) article suggesting `count(distinct)` can be slow in Postgres, together with options:

[postgresql COUNT(DISTINCT ...) very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250253/postgresql-countdistinct-very-slow)

Comment: . . It is not so much that `count(distinct)` is slow (which it is) but that the intermediate result might be so large.  For instance, by some definition, the city I'm in has 5.2 million trees, 3 rivers, and something like 250,000 "houses".  That generates a lot of intermediate data!

Comment: @GordonLinoff - that's a lot of trees!  But yes, granted - it's just an alternative (simpler) syntax that might make sense for smaller data sets.