# Speeding up count(distinct) of one column based on condition on other column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, query-optimization, where-clause

I have a MySQL table of 10 million rows and 3 columns, in following format:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     id                                     time                               num     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ca65e871-d758-437e-b76f-175234760e7b  2020-11-14 23:08:05.553770          11112222222 |
| ...                                                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

For running the first query below, I indexed the table on `(num, time)` and it works very fast (<5 milliseconds on 10 million rows table):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE time >= '2020-11-14 23:08:05.553752' AND num = 11112222222
```

However, I also need to execute `count(distinct)` clause on one column given the condition on other column, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT time) 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE time >= '2020-11-14 23:08:05.553752' AND num = 11112222222
```

This runs for around 20 milliseconds which is also very fast, but I was wondering is there a way to make it even faster (maybe similar to the execution time of the first query - less than 5 milliseconds) ?

Comment: 20 milliseconds is pretty fast.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree. But I am making a scoring app which needs to have 20 milliseconds response time overall. So from that point of view, I need to make it even more faster than this.

Comment: I doubt that the time with microsecond precise needs in DISTINCT...  moreover, I doubt that such precise is reasonable.

Comment: Please don't cross-post.