# How to decrease query execution time using JPQL query

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpql

I am trying to select some document table columns and map them into new object instead of returning the document as a whole. I am quite concerned about the execution time of the below query as it takes around ~4200 ms to execute for ~35,000 entries. What would be best solution to decrease the execution time? Is 4 seconds good time for 35,000 entries?

```
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT new it.homepackage.models.document.DocumentGetReviewCommand(" +
        "d.author.firstname, d.author.lastname, d.id, d.title, d.description, d.documentType.title, d.submissionDate)" +
        " FROM Document d" +
        " WHERE d.documentType IN :docTypes" +
        " AND d.documentState = it.homepackage.enums.DocumentState.SUBMITTED" +
        " AND :username <> d.author.username")
Page<DocumentGetReviewCommand> getDocumentsForReview(@Param(value = "username") String username,
                                                     Pageable pageable, 
                                                     @Param(value = "docTypes") List<DocumentType> docTypes);
```

Comment: Get the real SQL query, get an execution plan for it and see where you can improve it. Impossible to tell what the problem is from what you posted.

Comment: This isn't going to change everything, but why do you need `DISTINCT` on this query? Also, how large is that `:docTypes` list?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot to remove it after refactoring code. :typeList varies from 5 to 20

Answer (score 0):

You can start organizing the JOINs. When you use complex "train wreck" among the entities on JPQL (like `entity1.entity2.entity3.name`), Hibernate can generate weird (sometimes, invalid) SQLs.

First, the query could be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT new it.homepackage.models.document.DocumentGetReviewCommand(" +
        "author.firstname, author.lastname, d.id, d.title, d.description, documentType.title, d.submissionDate)" +
        " FROM Document d" +
        " JOIN d.author author " +
        " JOIN d.documentType documentType " +
        " WHERE d.documentType IN :docTypes" +
        " AND d.documentState = it.homepackage.enums.DocumentState.SUBMITTED" +
        " AND :username <> author.username
```

If the query is still slow, probably the cause is the `IN` clause. `IN` is equivalent to `OR`. Many itens on `IN` means a lot of `OR` on the SQL, what is generally difficult to the database optimize.

If the query is still slow, the second place to look is the `DISTINCT`. `DISTINCT` can sometimes [be replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6598931/2387977) by the `GROUP BY` for performance gain.