# How to use DISTINCT when I have multiple column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have the following query:

```
SELECT carBrand, carYear, carModel
FROM Cars;
```

What I want is to get **only different** car names.

I wrote this, but it is not what I want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT carBrand, carYear, carModel
FROM Cars;
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In my SqlServer, "select DISTINCT carBrand, carYear, carModel from Cars;" works perfectly

Comment: Personally I think it's better to use `OUTER APPLY` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64728511/4344976)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try thi:

```
SELECT carBrand, carYear, carModel 
FROM Cars 
GROUP BY carBrand, carYear, carModel;
```

Answer (score 18):

DISTINCT works on the entire row, not a specific column. If you want to get the unique names, select only that column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT carBrand FROM Cars
```

Answer (score 11):

I am not sure why the accepted answer has been accepted and certainly do not understand why it has been upvoted but the OP has the following in the question:

> I wrote this, but it is not what i want.

```
select DISTINCT carBrand, carYear, carModel from Cars;
```

The accepted answer has suggested to use:

```
SELECT carBrand , carYear ,carModel 
FROM Cars 
GROUP BY carBrand , carYear ,carModel;
```

which returns the exact same result as the OP's query. Actually the suggestion in the answer (use group by) is not even encouraged to be used for getting distinct results but should be used for aggregation. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164319/is-there-any-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct) answer for more info.

In addition, SQL Server is smart enough to understand that if there is no aggregation function in the query, then the query is actually asking for `distinct` so it will use `distinct` under the hood.

Distinct will do a distinct on the entire row as @MarkByers has indicated in his answer.

For those who want to test the above, here is a script that will create a table with 3 columns and then fill it with data. Both (`distinct` and `group by`) will return the same resultset.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cars](
    [carBrand] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [carYear] [int] NULL,
    [carModel] [varchar](50) NULL
)
go;
insert into Cars values('BMW', 2000, '328 i');
insert into Cars values('BMW', 2000, '328 i');
insert into Cars values('BMW', 2000, '328 i');
insert into Cars values('BMW', 2000, '3M');
```

Both queries will return this result:

```
carBrand    carYear    carModel
BMW         2000       328 i
BMW         2000       3M
```

---

**Conclusion**

DO NOT use `group by` if you want distinct records. Use `distinct`. Use `group by` when you use aggregate function such as `SUM`, `COUNT` etc.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you want.  For example if you want 'Toyota Corolla' and 'Toyota Camry', but ignore the year, then you could do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT carBrand + ' ' + carModel AS carName
FROM Cars;
```

Comment: Not trying to nitpick or be a jerk as SQL is not what I spend nearly as much time with,  but I certainly always felt that it is super simple to ONLY get `DISTINCT` on a single column , however I stumbled across this page as I was only getting 20 records from `SELECT distinct id from tablename`  and yet 1000's of records from `SELECT distinct id, pid from tablename`

Comment: `SELECT distinct id, pid from table `    == `select  distinct(id,pid)  from table `  that distinct keyword   works  as combination of all the column names.  it has secret  brackets that wrapss all the columns . may confuse people