# JPA @Query issues with the returned object

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I have added this in my DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT distinct LBL.cId, LBL from FooBar LBL ORDER BY LBL.collectedAt DESC")
    List<FooBar> findDistinctcIdOrderByCollectedAtDesc();
```

And then this is in my service

```
List<FooBar> fooBars = this.liveBusLocationDao.findDistinctcIdOrderByCollectedAtDesc();
```

And this is what I got when I debug contents of fooBars

```
fooBars = {ArrayList@11035}  size = 1
 0 = {Object[2]@11093} 
   0 = "string"
   1 = {FooBar@11095} "FooBar(cId=string, internalcId=123456789012, createdAt=2011-11-02 02:59:12.208, collectedAt=2017-10-06 14:26:26.544)"
```

How can I traverse this result?

Comment: this is Spring Data JPA not the JPA API. i.e there is no such `JPA @Query`. perhaps tag your question correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your Query is requesting on 2 attributes.
you can make a Custom class that as the id and the object or you could just remove `LBL.cId` from SELECT

Your request should be :

```
@Query("SELECT distinct LBL from FooBar LBL ORDER BY LBL.collectedAt DESC")
List<FooBar> findDistinctcIdOrderByCollectedAtDesc();
```

The distinct is working on the whole Row. take a look to it, if you are not shure about it, you can use `group by LBL`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10066187/3543153

Comment: But what result would this query give me? On which column is distinct condition applied?

Comment: i updated my answer. Distinct work on the whole row. You acn also replace distinct with a group by

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a result class and use special syntax in the jpa query if you want to use projection without getting the `Object[]` result.

```
package com.example

class ResultClass{

   int fieldOne;
   String fieldTwo;

  public (int fieldOne, intfieldTwo){
     // .. set fields
  }

}
```

and query:

```
@Query("SELECT distinct new com.example.ResultClass(LBL.cId, LBL.strProperty) from FooBar LBL ORDER BY LBL.collectedAt DESC")
    List<ResultClass> findDistinctcIdOrderByCollectedAtDesc();
```