# Oracle: DISTINCT vs. GROUP BY vs. ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, which of the following three queries is most efficient:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b
FROM tab
```

---

```
SELECT a, b
FROM tab
GROUP BY a, b
```

---

```
SELECT a, b
FROM
(SELECT a, b, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY a, b ORDER BY a, b) rn
 FROM tab )
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Can you take execution plans and see the cost of each?

Comment: It depends.  If one were always better than the others, then the others would not exist.  I will say, I only use `GROUP BY` if I'm performing some aggregate function (`SUM`,`MIN`,`MAX`), and I avoid `DISTINCT` in all but the simplest cases, because more often than not, it's the developer saying, "I'm getting duplicate rows back, and I don't understand the data model, so I'll slap a `DISTINCT` in here," and then down the road, some combination of data invalidates original implicit assumptions, and reports "break".

Comment: P.S. In your analytic function, since you're already `PARTITION`ing `BY` `a` and `b`, you'll never also have the opportunity to `ORDER BY` `a` and/or `b`:  your `ORDER BY` clause is essentially a no-op.  So either `ORDER BY` another (non-`a`, non-`b`) column, or, if you don't care, `ORDER BY NULL`.

Comment: I seriously doubt that the `ROW_NUMBER()` version is better than the other two.  The query optimizer _may_ be able to convert it to something similar to the others, but I sort of doubt it.  And yeah, you should be able to remove the `ORDER BY` in there.

Comment: It depends... If you were going to join this query onto another then I'd always use `row_number()` over distinct. You first two questions are [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164319/is-there-any-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct), including in Oracle, where someone has looked at the execution plan.

Comment: @X-Zero : Oracle insists on `ORDER BY` clause, but Tebbe's suggestion to `ORDER BY NULL` does seem to make sense.

@BobJarvis : when it comes to a query doesn't efficient = speed?

Comment: @Ben : Can you please explain why you would use `row_number()` when joining the query with another one (indeed, that is my case)?

Answer (score 1):

The first one is the correct choice, because the others are quirky and non-standard (and slightly perverse) ways of achieving the same aim.

Comment: Probably 1 and 2 are pretty similar, with the 3rd being slowest.