# select email, count(*) from emp group by email

Tags: sql

I have a table with columns `name` and `email`. The table has 10 records. I want to send an email for all the records. What is the query for that?

Comment: Your question title will achieve the same functional result as the DISTINCT statement.  But the latter spares you from having to use aggregates unnecessarily.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164319/is-there-any-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email FROM emp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DISTINCT email, ';')
FROM emp
```

Will output like: abc@gmail.com;pqr@yahoo.com... in one column