# GROUP BY and COUNT using ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Refering to this:
[Is there any difference between GROUP BY and DISTINCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164319/is-there-any-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct)

```
Given a table that looks like this:

name
------
barry
dave
bill
dave
dave
barry
john
This query:

SELECT name, count(*) AS count FROM table GROUP BY name;
Will produce output like this:

name    count
-------------
barry   2
dave    3
bill    1
john    1
```

What is the correct Rails convention here for ActiveModel to perform a GROUP BY with COUNT?

Comment: `Table.all.group(:name).count`

Answer (score 140, accepted):

`Distinct` and `Group By` are going to give you different results. To get the results you expect you'll want to use

```
Person.group(:name).count
(1.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, name AS name FROM "people" GROUP BY "people"."name"
=> {"Dan"=>3, "Dave"=>2, "Vic"=>1}
```

Seen above, group will return things as a hash. While distinct just returns the number of people in total, seen below.

```
Person.distinct(:name).count
(0.4ms)  SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "people"."id") FROM "people"
=> 6
```

Comment: which rails version is this?

Comment: 4.2+ from my experience

Comment: 4.2+ no need of `all`, simply `Person.group(:name).count`

Comment: For anyone looking to reproduce the distinct count query above, `Person.distinct(:name).count` will now return the same as `Person.count`.  That's obvsiously not the desired result.  These days, you would need to do `Person.distinct.count(:name)`, to get `6`.

Answer (score 8):

Note that the accepted answer will return a hash:

```
Tagging.joins(:tag).group(:name).size
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, `name` AS name FROM `taggings` INNER JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` GROUP BY `name`
 => {"applesauce"=>1, "oranges"=>2}
```

But what if you want to return the count plus some columns from different tables in a join. Then you also need to use the select ActiveRecord query:

```
collection = Tagging.select('COUNT(*) as total, taggings.taggable_id, taggings.taggable_type').joins(:tag).where(taggable_type: 'LineItem', taggable_id: ['5cad0dcc3ed1496086000031', '5cad0dcd3ed1496086000081'] ).group(:name)

collection.each do |item|
  puts item.taggable_id
  puts item.total
end

5cad0dcc3ed1496086000031
1
5cad0dcc3ed1496086000031
2
```

With this second approach, you can fetch additional details about a join relationship without any additional queries or loop constructs.

Answer (score 6):

another option:

```
Person.select(:name, 'COUNT(name)').group(:name)
```

this generate an array of people with attribute count

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
Person.select(:name).distinct(:name).count
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT name, count(*) AS count FROM table GROUP BY name;`

In Rails you'd write it like this: `Model.group(:name).count`

You can also order by the count by doing `Model.group(:name).order(:count_id).count`.
`Model.group(:name).order(count_id: :desc).count`

Doing a `.count` on a `.joins` will give you `count_all`. Doing a `.count` on a single table will give you a `count_id` to order by.