# How to get average of the last values by each table from database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 models: a `station` and `sensor_value` that are related by the station id.

```rb
class Station < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sensor_values, primary_key: :station_id, foreign_key: :station_id, dependent: :destroy
  validates :station_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

```rb
class SensorValue < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :station, primary_key: :station_id, foreign_key: :station_id
  validates :value, :type, :station_id, presence: true
end
```

One `station` can have several `sensor values`, each of `sensor values` saves different types of values (temperature, humidity, light).

I need to get the average for all the latest indicators from each station.My current solution to get the average temperature across all stations:

```rb
def last_sensors_values
  temperature = []

  Station.all.each do |st|
    next if st.sensor_values.empty?

    temperature_val = st.sensor_values.where(type: 'temperature').last.value
    temperature.push(temperature_val) unless temperature_val.zero?
  end

  {
    temperature: temperature.sum / temperature.size
  }
end
```

But I think it can be done with SQL, any ideas on how to improve this code?

Thanks for any help)

Updated:
Rails 5.2.5
Database PostgreSQL >= 10

Comment: What Rails version are you using? And what RDBMS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879150/group-by-and-count-using-activerecord ... but use `maximum` instead of count, then you should be able to divide the sum by the size ... ?

Answer (score 1):

First a small style comment... The model should be `Sensor` with an attribute `value`, instead of `SensorValue` with a attribute `value`.

This query gives you what you need, it's not written entirely in sql, but it generates a single sql query, which you can look at and use if that's your preference.

```rb
Station.joins(:sensors).select("avg(sensors.value) as avg_val").group("sensors.station_id")
```

Each `Station` model returned will have a `#avg_val` method containing the calculation you are looking for. Of course, you can add a `where` clause to limit to temperature sensors.