# What is difference between distinct and group by (without aggregate function)

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I want to know, for removing duplicate rows, which query is better ? (faster and more optimized):

```
select distinct col from table;
```

OR

```
select col from table group by col;
```

As you see, there is not any *aggregate function*, So which one is better ? Or in other word, what is the difference between them ?

Comment: How would you use DISTINCT to remove duplicate rows? How are you finding duplicates if not with an aggregate function like COUNT()?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between GROUP BY and DISTINCT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164319/is-there-any-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GROUP BY lets you use aggregate functions, like AVG, MAX, MIN, SUM, and COUNT. Other hand DISTINCT just removes duplicates.

You can read this answer too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/164544/4227703

Answer (score 0):

Please use `DISTINCT` for removing duplicate rows, as this construct was *specifically designed* for this purpose. It's shorter, easier to read and understand.