# mysql - do not display data if a certain condition is met

Tags: mysql

Sorry I don't really know how to make a title for this because I can't explain it really. for example i have here a table

```
c_id   emp_id   clinic_id
1      1         1
2      1         2
3      2         1
4      3         3
5      1         3
```

now i will do a query like this

```
select distinct * from table where clinic_id <> 1
```

And the result would be

```
c_id   emp_id   clinic_id
2      1         2
4      3         3
5      1         3
```

at this point I need help, if from the `where clinic_id <> 1` a certain `emp_id` is within its row of condition(Sorry for my bad english). for example `emp_id 1`. All `emp_id 1` must not be display also.
So the result would be just

```
c_id   emp_id   clinic_id
4      3         3 // *The result I want*
```

Comment: you either accept the results in the order you get them from in the db, or you impose your own ordering via an `order by` clause. you CAN have your client code simply suck in all the rows and then spit them out last-first, but that's not an sql problem.

Comment: Edit. It is more than just that data. `order by` doesn't help

Comment: In a normalised environment `DISTINCT *` is oxymoronic

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM table
WHERE clinic_id <> 1 
AND emp_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT emp_id 
            FROM table
            WHERE clinic_id = 1)
```

Try this one.

It uses the subquery to return the `emp_id`s which are in the same row as the 1 in the column `clinic_id`, and removes them from the resultset because you also don't want those `emo_id`s.

Also you could use a GROUP BY clause instead of DISTINCT. Usually GROUP BY would be turned into a distinct by the database if you are not using any aggregate functions, but sometimes they behave differently. If you are interested in this topic you can also see this question: [Is there any difference between GROUP BY and DISTINCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164319/is-there-any-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct#164323)

```
SELECT c_id, emp_id, clinic_id 
FROM clinics
WHERE clinic_id <> 1 
AND emp_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT emp_id 
            FROM clinics
            WHERE clinic_id = 1)
GROUP BY c_id, emp_id, clinic_id;
```

Comment: Yes, i can see the result and it work just fine. just 1 problem though, I have long stack of data here. and some clinic_id is duplicating

Comment: I don't see the problem tbh. Do you mean you have to check multiple clinic_ids at once? Then you could use `clinic_id NOT IN(clinid_id1, clinic_id2,...)` in the where clauses of the main and subquery

Comment: DISTINCT * is an oxymoron

Comment: Well, I think it communicates more clearly what the op wants to achieve than a group by. This is also the first time I heard that DISTINCT * is a bad thing, an explanation or an article/blogpost/etc. about this is much appreciated. [removed link to wrong dbms]

Comment: Please, mr. @Strawberry enlighten us.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` for this:

```
select distinct * 
from mytable as t1
where clinic_id <> 1 and 
      not exists (select 1
                  from mytable as t2
                  where t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id and t2.clinic_id = 1)
```

Comment: May I know please what kind of querying is this? Is this Subquery?

Comment: @Noobster Yes, `NOT EXISTS` uses a subquery. However, subquery execution terminates once a single row is returned.

Comment: Distinct *. ??. :-(

Answer (score 0):

For the result you're looking for, wouldn't something like this be simpler?

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table WHERE clinic_id !=1 AND emp_id !=1`

Here we're saying we want any clinic_id that is not 1 and any emp_id that is also not 1.

Since you're dealing with PHP, then you would simply substitute the numbers for the variables you're trying to not match.

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table WHERE clinic_id !=$session_variable AND emp_id !=$some_value`

Comment: Im coding with PHP and using session for `clinic_id` so I cant put a absolute value in the `emp_id` :)