# ORA-00937: - "not a single-group group function"

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, distinct

I have  a select

```
select distinct
    min(trunc(ALL_SUBS_DAY.CHARGE_AMT * SUP.SHARE_USAGE, 4)) + (ALL_SUBS_DAY.CHARGE_AMT - sum(trunc(ALL_SUBS_DAY.CHARGE_AMT * SUP.SHARE_USAGE, 4))) as CHARGE_AMT
from table names;
```

when I try to run it I get not a single-group group function.
If I do it like this

```
select 
    min(trunc(ALL_SUBS_DAY.CHARGE_AMT * SUP.SHARE_USAGE, 4)) + (ALL_SUBS_DAY.CHARGE_AMT - sum(trunc(ALL_SUBS_DAY.CHARGE_AMT * SUP.SHARE_USAGE, 4))) as CHARGE_AMT
from table names
group by SUBS_DAY.CHARGE_AMT, SUP.SHARE_USAGE;
```

it works. Wasn't distinct supposed to work like group by? Do I really need to list every single column or is there a way not to do it?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164319/is-there-any-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with `ALL_SUBS_DAY.CHARGE_AMT`.
You are not grouping by it, nor using an aggregate function on it.

```
+ (ALL_SUBS_DAY.CHARGE_AMT - sum(
```

select distinct
    min(trunc(ALL_SUBS_DAY.CHARGE_AMT * SUP.SHARE_USAGE, 4)) + (**ALL_SUBS_DAY.CHARGE_AMT** - sum(trunc(ALL_SUBS_DAY.CHARGE_AMT * SUP.SHARE_USAGE, 4))) as CHARGE_AMT
from table names;

---

`DISTINCT` work like group by only if you group by all columns/expressions and select all columns/expressions, e.g. -

```
select distinct a,b,c,d,e from t;
```

=

```
select a,b,c,d,e from t group by a,b,c,d,e;
```

---

Your first query returns a single row because you didn't aggregate by anything, which makes the `distinct` meaningless.

Comment: sum(trunc(ALL_SUBS_DAY.CHARGE_AMT * SUP.SHARE_USAGE, 4))). isn't sum an agregate function?

Comment: @EugeneCuz, this is not where I pointed you to. This column appears more then once.