# Group by SQL query in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have a query where I would like to consolidate by a Code that has two rows in the initial tab, however I keep getting an error Cannot group on Fields selected with '*'. Any ideas

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub get_code()    
   OptimizeVBA True: ShDel ("Workings")    
   Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
   Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

   With cn
       .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
       .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;IMEX=1;HDR=YES"";"
       .Open
   End With

   Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
   Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

   rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [Holdings$] WHERE [Holdings$].['Code$'] ='%91' GROUP BY ['Code']", cn

   Dim fld As ADODB.Field
   Dim i As Integer

   Sheets.Add.name = "Workings"
   With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Workings")
      i = 0
      For Each fld In rs.Fields
         i = i + 1
         .Cells(1, i).Value = fld.name
       Next fld
       .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
       .UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
   End With

   rs.Close
   cn.Close
   OptimizeVBA False
End Sub
```

Optimize just optimizes the workbook and SHdel deletes the sheet.

Comment: General GROUP BY tip: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: Perhaps you mean `ORDER BY ['Code']`? grouping by implies aggregation (min/max/avg/count) which you're doing none. or distinct to eliminate duplicates?

Comment: And why is the field quoted? Is there really quotes in that column header.

Comment: About @xQbert's comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/164544/1188513

Comment: @xQbert I wanted to sum by a var, but I have 50 column headers, maybe a subtotal is easier

Comment: what SQL engine is this?  would an windowfunction/analytic work to get the "sum" w/o any group by?  Such as `sum(var) over (partition by unique key/columns)`

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot group on Fields selected with '*'

Pretty explicit: you can't `GROUP BY` when you do `SELECT *`. Specify the field list explicitly.

```
SELECT [Code$], [Foobar] FROM [Holdings$] WHERE [Holdings$].['Code$'] ='%91' GROUP BY [Code$], [Foobar]
```

Note that all fields in the `SELECT` clause that aren't aggregates, must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

If there is no need to aggregate anything, you can remove the `GROUP BY` clause and do `SELECT DISTINCT` instead.

Comment: I see, makes sense when you put it like that

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved, instead of a simple SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: @jarlh [because it makes absolutely no difference whatsoever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/164544/1188513) and that's what the OP had.

Comment: @Mat's mug for SQL server, oracle that's true.  for mySQL it's not. and even in SQL server and oracle, more complex queries may result in different execution plans where the group by and distinct use result in different plans.  (we don't know the engine here though it's implied it's a MSFT product)

Comment: Well, that's a matter of taste. OP has 50 columns.

Comment: @xQbert my bad, per the connection string it would seem the source is an Excel worksheet, so the "engine" is the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider.

Comment: @jarlh OP is asking why they can't `GROUP BY` with `SELECT *`. Answering "use distinct instead" doesn't help OP understand.