# Distinct in R while connecting to PostgreSQL using DBI Package

Tags: r, postgresql, dbplyr

The below code prints:

```sql
SELECT "district_code" FROM sd_stage.table1 GROUP BY "district_code"
```

but I am expecting:

```
select distinct(district_code) from sd_stage.table1
```

Code:

```r
library(DBI)
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)

conn_obj <- DBI::dbConnect(RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL(), 
                           host = "127.0.0.1",
                           user = "testingdb",
                           password = "admin@123")
on.exit(DBI::dbDisconnect(conn_obj))

tbl_oil_root_segment <- dplyr::tbl(conn_obj, 
       dbplyr::in_schema('sd_stage','table1'))

tbl_oil_root_segment %>% distinct(oil_district) %>% show_query()
```

Output is correct but the query which is generated seems to be not 100%. So is there anyway I can implement the query?

Answer (score 1):

```r
tbl_oil_root_segment %>% select(oil_district) %>% distinct %>% show_query()
```

will create the query you expect.

However, note that in SQL `select distinct a from t` is the same as `select a from t group by a` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164319/is-there-any-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct)).

Comment: how can I use order_by in the above code you have mentioned so oil_district is in sorted order...

Comment: You can use `arrange` from dplyr.