# Syntax error when I add an additional field to select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select, expression

SQL novice hoping to get some help with a select statement

I can run this successfully:

```
select distinct t.QUALIFIEDORGUNITCODE as DEALERNUMBER, 
       count(distinct(t.TRANSACTIONID)) as TRANSACTION_VOLUME
  from adtdealers.transaction t
  where t.DATECREATED between '01-oct-17' and '01-nov-17'
  group by t.QUALIFIEDORGUNITCODE;
```

but if I attempt to add another field to the select I receive the following error:

> ORA-00936: missing expression 00936. 00000 - "missing expression" *Cause: *Action: Error at Line: 17 Column: 105

```
select to_char(t.DATECREATED, 'MON-DD') as DAY,
       count(distinct(t.TRANSACTIONID)) as TRANSACTION_VOLUME,
       distinct t.QUALIFIEDORGUNITCODE as DEALERNUMBER
  from adtdealers.transaction t
  where t.DATECREATED between '01-oct-17' and '01-nov-17'
  group by to_char(t.DATECREATED, 'MON-DD'), t.QUALIFIEDORGUNITCODE;
```

I can also run this succesfully:

```
select distinct t.QUALIFIEDORGUNITCODE as DEALERNUMBER,
       to_char(t.DATECREATED, 'MON-DD') as DAY
  from adtdealers.transaction t
  where t.DATECREATED between '01-oct-17' and '01-nov-17'
  group by t.QUALIFIEDORGUNITCODE, t.DATECREATED;
```

Comment: It would help greatly if you explained what a 00936 error is specifically; it's highly unlikely that the only error information is that number. What is the *specific* error message you're getting? It's on the screen right in front of you, so there's no reason for you not to include it here in your post.

Comment: Sorry about that.  00936 is an oracle error and the message given is
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 17 Column: 105

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost never need `select distinct` if you are using `group by`.  I think you simply intend:

```
select to_char(t.DATECREATED, 'MON-DD') as DAY,
       count(distinct t.TRANSACTIONID) as TRANSACTION_VOLUME, 
       t.QUALIFIEDORGUNITCODE as DEALERNUMBER
from adtdealers.transaction t
where t.DATECREATED between date '2017-10-01' and date '2017-11-01'
group by to_char(t.DATECREATED, 'MON-DD'), t.QUALIFIEDORGUNITCODE;
```

Notice that I changed the date literals to use ISO-standard formats at the `date` keyword.

Comment: Gordon, I truly appreciate it!  Your solution worked. If i might ask, why was the code I was attempting to use failing?  A quick search landed me on another stack post explaining how SQL handles "group by" and "distinct" as functionally the same.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164319/is-there-any-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct

In my first and third example I have "select distinct" and "group by", going by the above I would have expected it to fail as well.

Thanks again for the solution.

Comment: @silentbob343 . . . There is no stand-alone `distinct` keyword.  You need `select distinct`.

Answer (score 0):

In select statement only one time you can use distinct.