# Getting Table 1 data if Id is existing on Table 2

Tags: php, mysql

```html
Table 1

Category ID | Category Name

1             Lorem 1
2             Lorem 2
3             Lorem 3


Table 2

Post ID     | Post Content  | Category ID
1             Post 1          2
2             Post 2          2
3             Post 3          1
4             Post 4          3


Result

Categories:
Lorem 1
Lorem 2
Lorem 3
```

Category name will only display if there are post in that category.
List will be displayed using li

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.category_name
FROM table1
RIGHT JOIN table2 ON table1.category_id = table2.category_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Inner join with distinct caluse:

```
   select distinct CategoryName as categories from table1 a inner join table2 b
    on a.categoryid=b.categoryid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query =
"SELECT t1.cat_name
FROM t1,t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.cat_id
GROUP BY t1.cat_name";
```

You should change names of tables/attributes and choose your religion, lowercase or uppercase for all, and camel or snakecase

Answer (score 0):

Without getting too far into the differences of `DISTINCT` vs. `GROUP BY`, my preference in this case would be to use `DISTINCT`, since you are not using aggregates and you are  projecting a specific column in your `SELECT` statement (See this post for further details: [Is there any difference between GROUP BY and DISTINCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164319/is-there-any-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct)).

There are a couple of ways that you could approach this. Arguably using `INNER JOIN` is the most readable version (below), however if your style is typically to run lots of subqueries then the subquery version (further below) might appeal to you better:

**INNER JOIN method:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.category_name AS categories
FROM table_1 t1
  INNER JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.category_id = t2.category_id
ORDER BY 1
```

*See SQL Fiddle for active example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51de19/5*

**Subquery Method:**

```
SELECT t1.category_name AS categories
FROM table_1 t1
  WHERE category_id IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT category_id
    FROM table_2 t2
    )
ORDER BY 1
```

*See SQL Fiddle for active example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51de19/6*

Answer (score -1):

**Solution**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table_1.Category_Name FROM Table_1 LEFT JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1.Category_ID = Table_2.Category_ID
```

Comment: That won't work, `Table 1` is not a valid table name in MySQL

Comment: That is just an example. user have't wrote original table name.