# Select all items having silmutaneously 2different values at the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run an sql query and find all the books that have type="adventure" AND type="drama".

AND does not allow searching at the same time 2 different values of the same column.

My tables are like this

```
Books

 Bid    Bname     Author
  1     Sql       loren
  2     Monster   Mike
  3     Minnie    Michel

 ----------
 Copies

 Cid     Bid    Type
 1        1     Science
 2        1     Teaching
 3        2     Adventure
 4        3     Romance
 5        3     Drama
 6        3     Adventure
```

---

The result I want:

```
Bid     Title
 3      Minnie
```

The tables can't change

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do it, here is one using two exists conditions. Bottom line is that you have to check `copies` table twice.

```
SELECT * FROM books b
WHERE EXISTS 
(
   SELECT * FROM copies c1
   WHERE b.bid = c1.bid
   AND c1.type='adventure'
)
AND EXISTS 
(
   SELECT * FROM copies c2 
   WHERE b.bid = c2.bid
   AND c2.type='drama'
)
```

Comment: @NenadZivkovic why do we have to use EXISTS two times? I tried with single Exists but got no results and same with JOIN as well.

Comment: SELECT  b.Bid, b.Bname FROM books b
WHERE EXISTS 
(
   SELECT c1.Bid FROM copies c1
   INNER JOIN copies c2 ON c1.Bid = c2.Bid
   WHERE c1.type='adventure' AND b.Bid = c2.Bid  AND c2.type='drama'
) This query works as expected too. The only different with your query was that  in the query plan this query is doing at the end right semi join and yours is doing semi join.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with `JOIN`, here is the [DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p9hDZqrJZhhzsxGTqnukMp/2). And you can use `EXISTS` as per @NenadZivkovic answer.

```
select
    b.Bid,
    Bname as Title
from books b

join Copies c
on b.Bid = c.Bid
and c.Type ='Drama'

join Copies c1
on c.Bid = c1.Bid
and c1.Type = 'Adventure'

group by   
    b.Bid,
    Bname

order by
    b.Bid
```

Comment: My db has dublicates and this query returns the books mulitple times. I added "distinct" next to select and it worked fine! It also worked fine by adding on the end group by b.bid, b.title. Do you know which query is better;

Comment: I would suggest `group by`, also updated my answer. but you can read it here more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164319/is-there-any-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct